# Clean up rdf mappings and vocabularies

Tags: rdf

In the past I have imported automatically some vocabularies using rdfx/evoc and put some rdf mappings using rdfx ui. The module also made automatic rdf mappings with taxonomy terms and various fields that does not let me delete.

Now I need to clean up the mappings and reach astate of rdf mappings as it would be a fresh install.

RDF UI and other modules do not provide the possibility of deleting mappings.

What tables/fields I have to delete/alter from the database, so to clean up, without damaging the rest of the site?
How I can bring rdf_mapping, mapping BLOB to defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are more likely to get an answer in the RDF Extensions issue queue on drupa.org. see this comment as an answer to your question: http://drupal.org/node/1296820#comment-5068706

Comment: "- Uninstall evoc
- empty/TRUNCATE the tables rdf_mapping and rdfx_namespaces
- clear your caches (admin/config/development/performance or run drush cc all)". I would also add uninstalling any other semantic-web related module. Thanks